# GoLang Json FXCM

Tags: json, url, go

Why is this not dumping out the string?  Anyone have any ideas how to get this code working?

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
)

type Tick struct {
        Query string `json:"query"`
}

func main() {
        data := &Tick{Query: "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer?&callback=Tick"}
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
        enc.SetEscapeHTML(true)
        _ = enc.Encode(data)
        fmt.Println(string(buf.Tick()))
        fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Anyone know why this is invalid json or why this can not be parsed?  Or point out the fix how to make this work?

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "bytes"
        "io/ioutil"
        "github.com/pquerna/ffjson/ffjson"
)


type MsgRatesArray struct {
        RateQuote []MsgRateQuoteJson `json:"Rates"`
}
type MsgRateQuoteJson struct {
        SymbolName string `json:"Symbol"`
        SymbolBid int64 `json:"Bid"`
        SymbolAsk int64 `json:"Ask"`
        SymbolSpread int64 `json:"Spread"`
        SymbolPT string `json:"ProductType"`
}

var respBytes []byte

func main() {
    var msg MsgRatesArray
    response,err := http.Get("https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer?&callback=Tick")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    respBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)


    jsonBytes := respBytes[bytes.Index(respBytes, []byte("{")):bytes.LastIndex(respBytes, []byte("}"))+1]
    jsonString := string(jsonBytes)
    fmt.Println(jsonString)
    err = ffjson.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not JSON, but JSONP. If you would check the error you would see that :-)

Comment: Your code has syntax error. What is it you want printed? The content of the buffer? Then try printing `buf.String()`: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F0W8vG4avV). Or you want to print the response to that URL?

Comment: Already know the url being called no need to print out the url.  I am trying to get access to the json inside of jsonp.  Trying to figure out how to get access to the json data so I can pull out the tags for every pair and their price and put a time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your own http request to get the json, then strip out the non json stuff (everything before the first `{` and after the last `}`:

```
response,err := http.Get("https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer?&callback=Tick")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
respBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
jsonBytes := respBytes[bytes.Index(respBytes, []byte("{")):bytes.LastIndex(respBytes, []byte("}"))+1]
jsonString := string(jsonBytes)
fmt.Println(jsonString)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JyibZ3g6UA

Comment: Thank you!  I could not figure out how to strip off the start and end!  Now on to pulling out all the quotes!